# Excel 2016, assigning alternate values to cells to be summed

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a commission calculator and would like to add a fixed value for any cell with a positive value.  Specifically, if my cell range is A1 through A50, then I would like to add 5 for each cell with a value>0.  So if A1>0 then add 5, and so on.  If 10 cells had values, then my total would be 50.

Comment: Add a column with an if() formula - something like: if(a1>0, 5, 0) - copy it down the range and then just sum the new column.

Comment: Use an Array Formula =SUM(IF(A1:A50>0,5,0)) in any unused cell. Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to create an array formula else it shall return  0

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
`=5*COUNTIF(A1:A50,">0")`
Just write it where you want the result of the Sum

This formula uses `Countif` to count the cells (A1:A50) > 0
And multiply the result by 5
You can write 5 in any cell for example B1 in case you might change it, and change the formula to:
`=B1*COUNTIF(A1:A50,">0")`
and you will get the same result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this multiplier value (the 5) is stored in a seperate cell (or worksheet). The reason is, if you want to update the value it's easy.

You can't update the same cell with a formula - it's not possible for this type of recursive behavior, as such you'll need to add a new column to show this calcuated value

Therefore I suggest (with D1 being the cell of the multiplier value)

```
if (A2>0,A2*$D$1,A2)
```

[image]